# How to discard part of local changes to file

Tags: git

I have a file on which I have made several uncommited modifications.

```
git diff somefile
 a
 b
+Added line
 c
 d
-Removed line
 f
```

How can I discard only some of these changes (say the removed line)?

`git checkout somefile` will discard all changes, and I would like a mechanism similar to `git add -p` that lets me select which hunks to keep and which hunks to discard.

Comment: Indeed, although I did search prior to asking this question, I obviously used the wrong keywords. I'm requesting a close.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the changes you want to keep to the index and then checkout the file to kill the unstaged changes. And then optionally reset it to move the changes from the index to the working copy.

Answer (score 0):

[Interactive staging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) should help. Although, personally, I find GUI clients like [Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) much more helpful in this case.